# Java Thread.sleep() does not work properly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have some trouble with the delay command.

I want to show my logo for 2 seconds and then go to the MainMenu screen. But what it does is it shows a black screen for a couple of seconds, and goes to the MainMenu (I can see my logo for about 1ms):

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(PGSImage, 0, 0);
    game.batch.end();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
    dispose();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android

Comment: You shouldn't use Thread.sleep() on UI thread. Learn about Handlers

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. The desired behavior and error are explained, and enough code was provided to identify exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use such long methods as `sleep()` inside `render()` method because normally it is called 30 times per second (or even more frequently).

You can add timer to the `show()` method of your current `Screen`:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();

    float delay = 2; // seconds

    Timer.schedule(new Task(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

It will be called once your first `Screen` is displayed and then it will change your `Screen` to `MainMenuScreen` after 2 seconds.

Here `Timer` is `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer`.

You can also count time using `delta` parameter of the `render()` method. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798477/set-a-delay-in-libgdx-game) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are calling `render()` from the UI `Thread`. This means that `Thread.sleep()` will pause the execution of the UI `Thread` for 2 seconds.

If you want to delay execution one option is to use the `Handler` class. Make sure you read about Handlers and memory leaks.

Comment: To clarify this answer: it's libgdx, so the game is running on a dedicated GL thread, not the UI thread. But the problem is the same. Libgdx has an alternative to Handlers, the com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer class.